# Backing up ST3 settings

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I find that the new Sublime Text preferences architecture is pretty convenient.

It basically has us putting the keymap, preferences, and package-specific preferences, syntax-filetype mappings, syntax definitions, and color themes, all into the `Sublime Text 3/Packages/User` directory.

This makes it *very* tempting to turn this directory itself into a git repo.

Is this the intended purpose?

Comment: I don't know if it's the purpose, but it's certainly what I, and many ST users do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by OS there are :

Gnu/Linux :

```
$(HOME)/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Package Control.sublime-settings/Package Control.sublime-settings
```

Windows :

```
 %APPDATA%\sublime-text-3\Packages\User\Package Control.sublime-settings\Package Control.sublime-settings
```

Mac os x :

```
~/Library/Application Support/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Package Control.sublime-settings/Package Control.sublime-settings
```

I suppose it permits to recover all the packages via the upgrade command.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't know if it is the intended purpose, but I sure do. There's all a plugin available called [sublimall](http://sublimall.org/) that makes it pretty easy to sync packages, linters back and forth via machines. I've also used [dropbox](http://dropbox.com/) to sync pretty effortlessly just using symbolic links. I think that's been my favorite so far, but it doesn't have the backups and flexibility of git.

Answer (score 0):

I back the USER directory on my dropbox account, and then set symlink to it from my sublime text folder. Works like a charm.